# Get the records on count using dexie js with indexed db.

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

How can we get last 40 records from all records of a table.

As far as i know we can get the count of number of records which exits in table of indexed db.

For the same...

```
function doCount(){
        db.friends.toCollection().count(function (count) {
        console.log(count + " friends in total");
    });
```

Above will return whatever the count is in table.Now i wanted to get the last 40 records from table.Every time table will have different records.
is it possible to do so.
Can we also use ***.each***  with count!!I wanted to get count and as well as whatever the data that key holds i need to return those data and display it.

```js
 var db = new Dexie("MyDB");
        db.version(1).stores({
            friends: "id,name,shoeSize"
        });
        db.open();
        //
        // Populate some data
        //
        function populateSomeData() {
            log("Populating some data", "heading");
            return db.transaction("rw", db.friends, function () {
                db.friends.clear();
                db.friends.add({ id:1,name: "David", shoeSize: 43 });
                db.friends.add({ id:2,name: "Ylva", shoeSize: 37 });
                db.friends.add({ id:3,name: "Jon", shoeSize: 44 });
                db.friends.add({id:4, name: "Måns", shoeSize: 42 });
                db.friends.add({ id:5,name: "Daniel", shoeSize: 39 });
                db.friends.add({ id:6,name: "Nils", shoeSize: 45 });
                db.friends.add({ id:7,name: "Zlatan", shoeSize: 47 });
                // Log data from DB:
                db.friends.orderBy('name').each(function (friend) {
                    log(JSON.stringify(friend));
                });
            }).catch(function (e) {
                log(e, "error");
            });
        }
        //
        // Examples
        //
        function equalsAnyOf() {
            log("db.friends.where('name').anyOf('David', 'Zlatan', 'Daniel')", "heading");
            return db.friends.where('name').anyOf('David', 'Zlatan', 'Daniel')
                             .each(function (friend) {
                                 log(JSON.stringify(friend));
                             });
        }
        function equalsIgnoreCase() {
            log("db.friends.where('name').equalsIgnoreCase('david')", "heading");
            return db.friends.where('name').equalsIgnoreCase('david')
                             .each(function (friend) {
                                 log(JSON.stringify(friend));
                             });
        }
        function startsWithIgnoreCase() {
            log("db.friends.where('name').startsWithIgnoreCase('da')", "heading");
            return db.friends.where('name').startsWithIgnoreCase('da')
                             .each(function (friend) {
                                 log(JSON.stringify(friend));
                             });
        }
        function logicalOR() {
            log("db.friends.where('name').startsWithIgnoreCase('da').or('shoeSize').below(40)", "heading");
            return db.friends.where('name').startsWithIgnoreCase('da')
                             .or('shoeSize').below(40)
                             .each(function (friend) {
                                 log(JSON.stringify(friend));
                             });
        }
        function logicalAND() {
            log("db.friends.where('name').startsWithIgnoreCase('da').and(function (friend) { return friend.shoeSize > 40; })", "heading");
            return db.friends.where('name').startsWithIgnoreCase('da')
                .and(function (friend) { return friend.shoeSize > 40; })
                .each(function (friend) {
                    log(JSON.stringify(friend));
                });
        }
  var lakho =[];
  function doCount(){
   db.friends.toCollection().count(function (count) {
   lakho = count;
   console.log(count + " friends in total");
   var div = document.getElementById('po');
   div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + count;
  });
  console.log(lakho + "lakho");
  
  db.friends.where('id').between(1,3).count(function (count) {
   console.log(count + " friends in total");
   var div = document.getElementById('po');
   div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + count;
  });
  
  db.friends
    .where('shoeSize').above(9)
    .each (function (friend) {
   console.log("Found big friend: " + friend.name);
    });
}
        //
        // Helpers
        //
        function log(txt, clazz) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent = txt.toString();
            if (clazz) li.className = clazz;
            document.getElementById('log').appendChild(li);
        }
        function runSamples() {
            populateSomeData()
                .then(equalsAnyOf)
                .then(equalsIgnoreCase)
                .then(startsWithIgnoreCase)
                .then(logicalOR)
                .then(logicalAND)
    .then(doCount)
            .catch(function (e) {
                log(e, "error");
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dexie@latest/dist/dexie.js"></script>
    <body onload="runSamples();">
    <ul id="log"></ul>
 <div id="po"> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way i did it.

```
db.friends.orderBy('id')
.reverse()
.limit(3)
.toArray()
.then(function (results) {
    console.log (JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

Ref : [git hub ref](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/wiki/Table.offset())

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
db.yourTable
    .orderBy('id')
    .reverse()
    .limit(40)
    .each(callback)
```

It will iterate the last 40 records.

Comment: Hi David,
Huge fan of yours.
db.friends
    .orderBy('id')
    .reverse()
    .limit(3)
    .each(function (friend) {
        console.log("from last records"+JSON.stringify(friend));
    });
This will only return one record donno why i think it should return me all last 3 records but only got last record.